# How to access the authenticated & authorized User details?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-identity

**For Example:**

I have a simple application !

and by default the simple user registration page and login page is implemented by default (when we select mvc tempate).

So i added new properties for the User Registation Model.
Something like this.

```
public class ApplicationUser : IdentityUser
{
    [Required]
    [StringLength(255)]
    public string FirstName { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [StringLength(50)]
    public string LastName { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [StringLength(10)]
    public string Gender { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [StringLength(50)]
    public UserType UserType { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [StringLength(255)]
    public Department Depatment{ get; set; }

    [Required]
    [StringLength(50)]
    public Session Session { get; set; }
}
```

and these properties are also added to the RegisterViewModel for rendering the registration page and so..

**Question:**

When the new user is register ! and login to the application.
So now i want to access logged-In user details?
i-e FirstName, LastName, Gender, etc..

I tried `User.Identity.?` but there is no such properties ? that previously i added to the ApplicationUser ?

i want to access all the LoggedIn User Properties and render it in the view.

```
[Authorize]
public ActionResult Index()
{
    // Retreiving LoggedIn User Details.
    // ....
    // ....
    // LoggedInUserInfo = // assigning all the User details to the LoggedUserInfo

    return View(LoggedInUserInfo); // LoggedInUserInfo is a separete class that having several properties such as firstName, lastName, Gener, etc...
}
```

Comment: Where is your "ApplicationUser" get's persisted ?

Comment: `~/Models/IdentityModels.cs` inside identity.cs file

Answer (score 1):

You could inject the UserManager class and then use it to get the Application User info.

```
private UserManager<ApplicationUser> _userManager;
public YourController(UserManager<ApplicationUser> userManager)
{
_userManager = userManager;
}
```

Them in your method:

```
var user = await _userManager.GetUserAsync(User);
var firstName = user.FirstName;
var lastName = user.LastName;
var middleName = user.MiddleName;
var documentNumber = user.DocumentNumber;
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

In conjunction with your `ApplicationDbContext` and an extension method `GetUserId()` you can find the logged-in `ApplicationUser`:

```
ApplicationUser loggedInUser = applicationDbContext.Users.Find(HttpContext.User.Identity.GetUserId());
```

Comment: `HttpContext.Current` ?  Current is not accessible ? which namespace i have to include ?

Comment: @Rehan.S I have edited my answer because `Current` was indeed wrong in this context. Also note that if you are able to inject dependencies in you controller, abarrenechea's solution is also a good one.